# Exiting ant target without failing build

Tags: ant, exit

I'm looking for a way to exit a target and continue running the ant code without exiting the overall process. Something like the below but I get errors.

```
<target name="foo">
<some-task/>
<another-task/>

<condition property="should.exit">
(condition check here....)
</condition>

<exit if="should.exit" message="some message"/>

(skipped tasks if "should.exit" is true)

</target>
```

Errors I get:

```
Problem: failed to create task or type exit   
[sshexec]      [echo] Cause: The name is undefined.   
[sshexec]    
[sshexec]      [echo] Action: Check the spelling.   
[sshexec]    
[sshexec]      [echo] Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.   
[sshexec]      [echo] Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.   
[sshexec]    
[sshexec]      [echo]    [sshexec]    
[sshexec]      [echo]                    ERROR Error error
```

Comment: Please check if the particular task supports `failonerror` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<target name="foo">
<some-task/>
<another-task/>

<condition property="should.exit">
(condition check here....)
</condition>

<fail message="failing">
    <condition>
        <equals arg1="${should.exit}" arg2="true"/>
    </condition>
</fail>

(skipped tasks if "should.exit" is true)

</target>
```